# Copying some data of an NSManagedObject to another

Tags: objective-c

I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass (let's call it) `Car` with 2 properties of type `NSNumber`: `speed` and `fuel`.

If I have an instance of the class `Car` and I copy some values to a new instance, are these values connected or are just copied like using the method `copy`?

Here the code with my doubt:

```
// The object ferrari was previously obtained from fetch request

Car *lotus = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Repetition" 
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

// solution 1
lotus.speed = ferrari.speed;
lotus.fuel = ferrari.fuel; 

// solution 2 
lotus.speed = [ferrari.speed copy];
lotus.fuel = [ferrari.fuel copy];
```

Giving that I want to be sure that the two object are independent, so changing properties or `lotus` doesn't have to change properties of `ferrari` can I just use the solution 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSNumber` objects are *immutable*. If you assign

```
lotus.speed = ferrari.speed;
```

then both attributes point to the same `NSNumber` object, but you cannot *change*
that object. You can only assign a *new object*:

```
ferrari.speed = @(454);
```

but that will not change the value of `lotus.speed`. So you don't need to copy the
object. The same is true for `NSString` attributes.